# Is it better to wrap the label tag around a form item or use the "for" attribute in HTML?

Tags: html, label

I know that you can use both but is it better to use one over the other? If so, why?

**Example of "for" attribute:**

```
<input type="text" id="male"><label for="male">Male</label>
```

**Example of wrap:**

```
<label>Age:<input type="text"></label>
```

Comment: I'd wrap the label around the input just because I like to avoid adding superfluous `id` attributes

Comment: As mentioned in one of the answers, the for attribute is sometimes useful. The w3c's example of putting the label and corresponding input into separate table cells is a potential case where you'd need them separate: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1

Comment: Ok thanks that cleared things up for me.

Comment: For what it's worth, you should always use the `for` attribute and use IDs with all form elements, even if the label wraps the element. This greatly helps users with accessibility issues - many screen readers, today, look for the `for` attribute even if the label wraps an element. At any rate, it's good practice.

Comment: Maybe the screen readers should be better?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Semantically, both possibilities are the same. But depending on what layout you want, there are advantages and disadvantages for the two possibilites. For example, if you want that the label is at an entirely different place, it would not make any sense to put the input into the label. But if you want to be able to make a hover-effect via css, that sets e. g. a background for both the label and the area around the input, it would be better to put the input into the label.

Comment: there are also +/- in terms of usability and accessibility, but as @matthias said, it depends...

Comment: IMO the main case for NOT wrapping an element with the label is using media queries or CSS in general to arbitrarily position the label element.  What if you need to hide the label for different layout, or move it somewhere with absolute position for whatever reason?  If it's wrapped, you can't do those things with CSS.  Check out CSS Zen Garden for examples of the many ways a standardized document can be styled with CSS alone.

Comment: not to drag this into the ground, but adding inline tags around the actual label mitigates styling concerns. consider `<label for="name"><span class="label">Name</span><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></label>`

Comment: Someone asked a question today that demonstrates a semantic difference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501497/why-the-onclick-element-will-trigger-twice-for-label-element/24501565?noredirect=1#comment37931213_24501565 When you wrap the label around the input, events on the input bubble to the label.

Comment: @JoeyT Albeit I kind of agree with you, there would be a multitude of ways of hiding the label text with CSS (text-indent, color, font-size etc), not that these are desirable, but it shouldn't be a reason not to wrap labels around inputs.

Answer (score 28):

according to 
http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-WCAG20-TECHS-20080430/H44.html

> some assistive technologies do not correctly handle implicit labels

So when you wrap, you may also want to provide the "for" attribute to the label element.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for accessibility / a11y specific reasoning / answers and this was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Is this still the case? A lot has changed in the 10 years since that was written.

Comment: According to this w3 article (last updated July 2019), "explicit labels are [still] better supported by assistive technology".   https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/labels/

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The wrap allows to drop the `for` attribute, which in turn allows to omit the `id' attribute on the input element. Great for templates or any forms that need to be used in multiple instances on a page.

Comment: Please explain, because as I read your link, it's ok to wrap and drop the "for" attribute, see  `...and if you use the for attribute it has to refer to a form element, but you don't have to use the attribute...`

Comment: I was referring specifically to "The for attribute of the label element must refer to a form control." (http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/label.html). However, I think it was a mistake for me to interpret that instruction to mean "The label element must have a for attribute which refers to a form control". It's not quite the same thing; I was wrong (see http://stackoverflow.com/q/27826996/1430996).

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter. Both accomplish the same things in terms of defining the relationship between the label and field.

Answer (score 1):

Embedding the input in the label also affects the wrapping behaviour.  `<label><checkbox/>Value with spaces</label>` will wrap as a single unit by default.  Whereas `<checkbox id="check"/><label for="check">Value with spaces</label>` will wrap the text with breaks at spaces and will wrap the label to a new line but leave the checkbox above.

Answer (score 0):

If it counts for anything, frameworks like ASP.NET put the `label` element next to the `input`/`select`/`textarea` elements and use the `label`'s `for` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The 'label for' syntax means the label you have created is intended to be a label for the input with id 'inp'.  If you click this label in most browsers the cursor focus will land on the 'inp' input element.  It's a nice little way of linking a label with its corresponding form control.

I'm not aware of compatibility issues, or any around performance.  To me it seems syntactically sound, and as far as I'm aware the CSS spec claims that both are valid.

Comment: The focusing feature also applies to the same input if it's nested in the label.

Comment: Was just saying that this allows you to specify which, rather than effectively tying them together by nesting.  Not sure what you mean about CSS spec..?

Comment: I see - I meant HTML spec - got confused.

Answer (score 0):

The relationship is more explicitly defined when using the `for` syntax, although I believe most browsers implement the same behaviour for both.

A matter of preference, I think. Personally I would use the `for` syntax as I think it makes more semantical sense than for the `input` element to be a part of its `label` element.