# Why the onclick element will trigger twice for label element

Tags: javascript, html

```js
      window.onload = function(){
         var wow = document.getElementById("wow");
      wow.onclick = function(){
          alert("hi");
      }
      }
```

```html
    <label id="wow"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="value">Text</label>
```

This is my code, when I clicked on "Text" it will alert hi twice but when I clicked on the box, the `onclick` element will only trigger once, why?

Comment: do you need the alert on windows onload?

Comment: @Niang nope when the text is clicked

Answer (score 85, accepted):

When you click on the label, it triggers the click handler, and you get an alert.

But clicking on a label also automatically sends a click event to the associated input element, so this is treated as a click on the checkbox. Then event bubbling causes that click event to be triggered on the containing element, which is the label, so your handler is run again.

If you change your HTML to this, you won't get the double alert:

```
<input id="wowcb" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="value">
<label id="wow" for="wowcb">Text</label>
```

The label is now associated with the checkbox using the `for` attribute instead of wrapping around it.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/fMMAz/3/)

Comment: I guess I've never noticed this because I would generally just put the "click" handler on the `<input>`, not the label. It's curious behavior and I'm not sure I can think of a reason it'd be useful.

Comment: You could also stop event propagation.

Comment: Ideally one would bind a change event handler instead. Great for accessibility.

Comment: @FelixKling You can't bind a change handler to the label, AFAIK.

Comment: Or put the listener on the checkbox. ;-)

Comment: @MMiller Yes, but you'd have to add a click handler on the checkbox for that.

Comment: Oh yeah, I meant to the input. But then the problem would not occur anyways (with the click event handler).

Comment: @RobG I assume he did it this way because he wants to do something _only_ when the user clicks on the label, not the checkbox.

Comment: Stopping event propagation probably would not help.  As far as I can tell there are two completely separate events generated.

Comment: What you would have to do is add a click handler on the checkbox, and put `stopPropagation` into that.

Comment: The issue with this solution is that changes to the markup will have significant (and possibly quite unexpected) effects on the behaviour of the script.

Comment: There are almost no differences between wrapping a label and using `for`. This is probably one of the few. See the linked question.

Comment: Im making a impersonator and i need a fix for this:  What makes a browser execute another click even on input when the event bubbles to label? I make a click on action in checkbox but when it bubbles to the label the browser will create another click event on input.

Comment: @joelharkes One of the main features of using labels is that you can click on the label and it will be treated as if you'd clicked on the associated element. It doesn't matter how the event reached the label, by clicking on it directly or by it bubbling from a contained element.

Comment: I just run into this problem, the first time. Put the checkbox out of label is not an option if you use Bootstrap.

Comment: Handle checkbox's change worked nicely, thanks @FelixKling :)

Comment: Regarding this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40368276/window-click-event-is-getting-called-twice this answer doesn't answer the question. My label isn't wrapped around the input. How can I fix it then?

Comment: But in your case you're putting the handler on `window`, which wraps both of them, so it's essentially the same thing. Clicking on the label bubbles to the window, and also triggers a click on the checkbox, which bubbles to the window.

Comment: See @RobG's answer, where he checks the event target to see which element is actually getting the event.

Comment: Maybe you can change <label> to <div>

Comment: @meizilp Then you lose both the semantic relationship that the text is a label for the checkbox and also the automatic behavior of clicking on the label as a proxy for clicking on the checkbox. You can fix the latter with extra JS.

Answer (score 5):

If your intention is to respond only to clicks on the label and not on the checkbox, you can look at the *event.target* property. It references the element that called the listener so that if the click wasn't on that element, don't to the action:

```
window.onload = function(){
  var el = document.getElementById('wow');
  el.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

    if (this === event.target) {
      /* click was on label */
      alert('click was on label');

    } else {
      /* click was on checkbox */
      event.stopPropagation();
      return false;
    }

  }, false);
}
```

If, on the other hand, you want to only respond to clicks on the checkbox (where a click on the label also produces a click on the checkbox), then do the reverse. Do nothing for clicks on the label and let ones from the checkbox through:

```
window.onload = function(){
  var el = document.getElementById('foolabel');
  el.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

    if (this === event.target) {
      /* click was on label */
      event.stopPropagation();
      return false;

    } else {

      /*
      ** click is from checkbox, initiated by click on label
      ** or checkbox                                  
      */

      alert('click from checkbox');
    }

  }, false);
}
```

This version seems to have the most natural behaviour. However, changing the markup so that the label no longer wraps the checkbox will mean the listener is not called.

Answer (score 4):

Event bubble.

The checkbox is the child node of the label. You click the checkbox. Event bubble to the label. Then alert pop up twice.

To prevent alert pop up twice when you click the checkbox. You can change you onclick function into this:

```
wow.onclick = function(e){
    alert('hi');
    stopBubble(e);
}


function stopBubble(e)  
{  
    if (e && e.stopPropagation)  
        e.stopPropagation()  
    else 
        window.event.cancelBubble=true 
}
```

Hope this can work for you.

Comment: I don't think this is the correct answer. An event handler on the containing `<label>` tag should receive a bubbled event only once. Browsers generate *two* "click" events, one with the `<input>` element as the target and one with the `<label>` as the target.

Comment: Two times pop up. One comes from click the label. The other is click the input bubble to the label. I think this can explain that.: )

Comment: No, bubbling only involves **one** event object that's delivered to event handlers on parent elements. In this case, the event object is different on the two times the handler is invoked.

Comment: It doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/fMMAz/5/ Propagation from the label to the checkbox isn't bubbling, it's something very specific to labels.

Comment: No it doesn't. I clicked on "Text" and got two alerts in Chrome.

Comment: And @Pointy sorry guys, I mixed this up : (

Answer (score 1):

The Label tag will be associated with the input tag inside it. So when you click the label, it will also trigger a click event for the input, then bubble to the label itself.

See this:

```
document.getElementById("winput").addEventListener('click', function(event){
     alert('input click');

     //stop bubble
     event.stopPropagation();

 }, false);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/96vPP/

Answer (score 0):

Rammed headfirst into this gotcha again and decided to prove what it did to myself, hopefully helping me remember. To help future people to whom the above might not be clear enough, here the example I made.

https://jsfiddle.net/ashes/0bcauenm/

```
$(".someBigContainer").on("click", "input[type=checkbox]", ()=> {
    $output.val("Clicked: checkbox\n" + $output.val());
});
```

edit: added the link with a snipped of the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the simplest answer. Just add a span around your text and stop event propagation.

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var wow = document.getElementById("wow");
    wow.onclick = function(){
        alert("hi");
    }
}
```

```html
<label id="wow">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="value">
    <span onclick="event.stopPropagation()">Text</span>
</label>
```

Or without inline-javaScript

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var wow = document.getElementById("wow");
    wow.onclick = function(){
        alert("hi");
    }

    var span = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
    span.onclick = function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

```html
<label id="wow">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="value">
    <span>Text</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Neither of these solutions work 100% as is. You have multiple space characters that fall into the <span> which are found: before the checkbox, before "Text" right in between the checkbox and the "Text" where if you click just right you get a double alert. Also, you get double alert if you are very accurate to click anywhere 1px right outside the border of the checkbox. (I'm using windows 10, chrome 98)

Answer (score 0):

For those using React and Material UI - I've encountered this issue on one of my forms.  `event.preventDefault()` is stopping the event from bubbling as described by the accepted answer.

```
  <Button
    onClick={(event) => {
      event.preventDefault()
      this.handleCardClick(planName)
    }}
  >
    <FormControl component="fieldset">
      <RadioGroup
        row
        value={selectedPlan}
      >
        <FormControlLabel
          control={<Radio color="secondary" />}
          label={label}
        />
      </RadioGroup>
    </FormControl>
  </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `change` to listen for events instead of `click`