# Why does html label for trigger callback on containing div twice?

Tags: javascript, html

I saw [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501497/why-the-onclick-element-will-trigger-twice-for-label-element) that asks something similar, but the difference is that they put the input element inside the `label` tag, whereas mine is outside:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <style>
      div {
        background-color: #AAA;
        width: 100px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id='foo' onClick="alert('clicked')">
      <label for='foo-pie'>Pick Foo:</label>
      <select id='foo-pie' name='wat[wat]'>
        <option value='pie'>Foo</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I click on the div, not on the label, the alert triggers once. If I click on the label, the alert triggers twice. Why is this? It seems to me like the alert should trigger once regardless. If I remove the `for=` it only triggers once, which suggests to me that there's some sort of event bubbling going on... [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1p16ckht/)

Comment: The answer is the same - using the `for` attribute is like putting the input inside the label

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because label is an interactive element. When clicked it triggers an activation event on its associated element. This activation event usually causes a click event, so you get two clicks instead of one. One for the actual user click and one caused by the activation event.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element

> For example, on platforms where clicking a checkbox label checks the
>   checkbox, clicking the label in the following snippet could trigger
>   the user agent to run synthetic click activation steps on the input
>   element, as if the element itself had been triggered by the user:
>
> `<label><input type=checkbox name=lost> Lost</label>`
>
> On other
>   platforms, the behavior might be just to focus the control, or do
>   nothing.

While the example from the docs shows an onClick for the input element, the event would bubble up so in your case your div gets the bubbled click event

[Interactive-content doc](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content-0)

To prevent this you can prevent the default action, or use stopPropagation to stop the event from bubbling up.

**Inline**

```
<label onclick="return false;" for='foo-pie'>Pick Foo:</label>
```

**in code**

HTML

```
<label id="foolabel" for='foo-pie'>Pick Foo:</label>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("foolabel").addEventListener(function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); //Or
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**Example**

```html
<div id='foo' onClick="alert('clicked')">
  <label onclick="event.stopPropagation();" for='foo-pie'>Pick Foo:</label>
  <select id='foo-pie' name='wat[wat]'>
    <option value='pie'>Foo</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My theory is that this is a feature called event propagation, and by defining your `<div>` with the `onclick` attribute it has somehow bound that event to the children as well.

Try throwing `e.stopPropagation` into your event callback and it should stop it from being called multiple times.

[MDN Example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Examples#Example_5:_Event_Propagation)