# EventListener showing wrong target

Tags: javascript

I have the following JS code

```
var existingMenus = document.getElementsByClassName('multiSelectMenu');
for (var i = 0; i < existingMenus.length; i++) {
    var existingMenu = existingMenus[i];
    var existingMenuHTML = [];
    var targetChildren = existingMenu.parentElement.nextElementSibling.children;
    console.log(targetChildren)
    // Here I'm adding +1 to the ID as it appears starting at zero with a styled checkbox does not work correctly
    for (var x = 0; x < targetChildren.length; x++) {
        if (targetChildren[x].selected) {
            existingMenuHTML += '<li><input class="dropdown-input" type="checkbox" id="' + (x + 1) + '" data-label="' + targetChildren[x].textContent + '" checked="true"/><label class="multiLabel" for="' + (x +
                1) + '"><span></span> ' + targetChildren[x].textContent + ' </label></li>';
        } else {
            existingMenuHTML += '<li><input class="dropdown-input" type="checkbox" id="' + (x + 1) + '" data-label="' + targetChildren[x].textContent + '"/><label class="multiLabel" for="' + (x + 1) +
                '"><span></span> ' + targetChildren[x].textContent + ' </label></li>';
        }
    }
    existingMenu.innerHTML += existingMenuHTML;
    console.log(existingMenuHTML)
    var inputs = existingMenu.children;
    console.log(inputs);
    for (var w = 0; w < inputs.length; w++) {
        var input = inputs[w].children[0];
        console.log(input);
        input.addEventListener('click', function() {
            console.log('--------------')
            console.log(event)
            var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;
            console.log(targetElement);
            var elementParent = targetElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
            console.log(elementParent)
            if (!elementParent.classList.contains('open')) {
                elementParent.className += ' open';
            }
            var multiList = elementParent.nextSibling.querySelector('[value="' + targetElement.dataset.label + '"]');
            console.log(multiList)
            // Subtracting one to account for the plus one I added above
            var inputId = targetElement.id - 1;
            if (targetElement.checked == true) {
                multiList.selected = "selcted";
            } else {
                multiList.selected = "";
            }
            console.log('--------------')
        });
    }
}
```

The code works correctly on the first instance of the multiPick but all others on page trigger the first multiSelectMenu items even though I was clicking on the 3rd multiSelectMenu on page.

Here is a screen shot of the console,
[image]

Here is a code pen, https://jsfiddle.net/6s3rc8d7/ When you click the 'label' and not the checkbox it has the same issue I am seeing.

Comment: You're missing the `event` argument to the event listener function. Not all browsers allow you to access it as a global variable.

Comment: Can you make an executable [Stack Snippet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0)?

Comment: I've added the event parameter but sadly it is still having the same issue. I can try to create a codePen but I am using a language called VisualForce that just renders HTML so there it is not exactly easy to convert the post compiled markup.

Comment: CodePen Adding, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason behind getting the different **event.target** in your fiddle is due to the below code snippet in your html.

```
 <input class="dropdown-input" type="checkbox" id="1" data-label="English only">
 <label class="multiLabel" for="1"><span></span> English only </label>
```

you can see that in the label element, you have the **for** attribute which contains the **id** of the input element. The functionality of **for** attribute is that the value of this identifies which form element a label is bound to. When you click on the label **it will simulate the click event** of the bounded element. This is why when you click the label , in your script the **event.target** is the input the label is bonded with.

More on **for** attribute you can read here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501497/why-the-onclick-element-will-trigger-twice-for-label-element/24501565#24501565

Answer (score 0):

I was able to rework the code and added the EventListener to the label instead of the checkbox.