# window click event is getting called twice

Tags: javascript, css, checkbox, dom-events, event-bubbling

I have an click event on `window`. There is also a checkbox and a label for the checkbox. When you click on the label, the `window's` click event gets called twice, once for the checkbox, and once for the label.

I tried adding `e.stopPropagation();` to the events listener, but it didn't help. Why is the event getting called twice, and what can I do to fix it?

#### JSFiddle

```js
var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox-id');

window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log(checkbox.checked, e.target)
});

console.clear();
```

```css
input {
  display: none;
}
label {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
}
input:checked label {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox-id" />
<label for="checkbox-id"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

The event bubbles up. To stop that, use the `stopPropagation()` method:

var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox-id');

```
window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log(checkbox.checked, e.target)
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

For more details on event order and bubbling: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Comment: The checkbox never gets checked in this answer

Comment: You're right. The 'edit' prevents the click. I'm reversing the edit.

Comment: This doesn't work, as I said in the question. Can you please test out your code before posting it?