# Double call by click from component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

The calling my own event onToggle by click from this loop gives me double call, WHY?

```
    const item = params.map((item) => {
    return (
        <label key={item.key} 
               className={`btn btn-outline-${item.checked? 'primary active' : 'secondary'}`} 
               onClick={() => {
                  onToggle(item.key)
               }}>
            <input type='radio' autoComplete="off" cheked={item.checked}/> {item.content}
        </label>
    )
})
```

Comment: dont know react that well but I'm pretty sure cheked is misspelled and should be 'checked', and I would expect that your onClick event should be in the input element not the label element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why the onclick element will trigger twice for label element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501497/why-the-onclick-element-will-trigger-twice-for-label-element)