# My click handler is firing twice with different values in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I can't for the life of me figure out why my onClick handler is being called twice...

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const AllModels = ({
  label,
  name,
  checked,
  handleSelectAll
}: {
  label: string;
  name: string;
  checked: boolean;
  handleSelectAll: () => void;
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="checkbox" onClick={handleSelectAll}>
        <input
          className="checkbox-input"
          id="all-models"
          type="checkbox"
          name={name}
          value={`${checked}`}
        />
        <label className="label label--checkbox" htmlFor="all-models">
          <span className="label-title">{label}</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export const App = (): React.ReactElement => {
  const [allModelsChecked, setAllModelsChecked] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const handleSelectAll = (): void => {
    console.log({ allModelsChecked });
    if (allModelsChecked) {
      setAllModelsChecked(false);
    } else {
      setAllModelsChecked(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <AllModels
      label="All Models"
      name="allModels"
      checked={allModelsChecked}
      handleSelectAll={handleSelectAll}
    />
  );
};
```

The console log is showing

```
{allModelsChecked: false}
{allModelsChecked: true}
```

I am running `React.StrictMode`, but I don't believe I am mutating state as far as I can tell.

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-tree-gzofx?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example (i.e codesandbox)? Unless you're clicking the button twice, this example logs once, so the problem is probably elsewhere

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-tree-gzofx?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Nice find! This seems to be the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501497/why-the-onclick-element-will-trigger-twice-for-label-element

Comment: I'd suggest moving the label out like so so it's not in the hierarchy https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-lamport-t4rkq?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input `type=checkbox` accept checked prop for input tag. Change the value to checked and that will fix the problem

```
<input
 className="checkbox-input"
 id="all-models"
 type="checkbox"
 name={name}
 // value={`${checked}`}
 checked={checked}
/>
```

you can see the chain of event logs in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-shape-7l8cl?file=/src/App.tsx:410-650)