# JQuery is:checked returning two values every click

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a simple bit of code to show a div of information if a checkbox has been checked, and to hide that div if it is not checked. While building, I ran into an issue that I cannot find any information to resolve. To simplify the problem, I have an if statement, and if the input is checked, it will log "checked". if it isn't checked, it will log "not checked".

`$("#my-id")` is a div containing a label with a checkbox input inside it:

```
<div id='my-id'>
  <span>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      test
    </label>
  </span>
</div>
```

Clicking on it selects and deselects the checkbox input.

```
$("#my-id").unbind('click').click(function(){
    if($(this).find('input').is(':checked')){
        console.log('checked');
    }
    else {
      console.log('not checked');
    }
});
```

What I'm seeing in the log with one click is:

```
not checked
checked
```

Then when I click the same one again, is shows

```
checked
not checked
```

This is messing with the `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` functions because they end up getting called twice, and I have parts of my page sliding up and down and up and down. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. I'm sure there is something about jQuery, or it's functions that I do not understand yet.

Comment: so why are you not binding to the checkbox changed event?

Comment: unclear how that code would fire the console.log 2 times. I think we need to get a demo of this in action to fully help you out.

Comment: Your code works, and I even tested it with plain JS, so something else must be going on in your code - likely triggering a "click" somewhere: https://jsfiddle.net/359jcnrx/.

Comment: Ryan, thanks for setting this up in jsfiddle. When I click on it, and look at the log, 'not checked' and 'checked' both are showing up, and that's where my confusion is. Why are both outcomes of the If statement being executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to happen only when you click on the `<label>` tag. When you click the `<div>`, `<span>`, or `<input>` it works correctly.

This behavior might be explained here: [Why the onclick element will trigger twice for label element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501497/why-the-onclick-element-will-trigger-twice-for-label-element).

One fix is to add `return false;` to your click handler:

```
$("#my-id").unbind('click').click(function(){
    if($(this).find('input').is(':checked')){
        console.log('checked');
    }
    else {
      console.log('not checked');
    }
    return false; // Prevents event handler from being called twice
});
```

You can also call `.preventDefault()` on the event object to prevent it from being called twice:

```
$("#my-id").unbind('click').click(function(e){
    if($(this).find('input').is(':checked')){
        console.log('checked');
    }
    else {
      console.log('not checked');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing that link, I think that is what is going on. I was loosing my mind trying to understand why it was happening lol.

Comment: e.preventDefault() removes the click event that the label creates, and then I used jQuery to set the input prop checked as true or false. After doing that, the rest of the code is behaving normally. Kinda defeats the purpose of having the checkbox inside the label if you are planning on adding your own click events to it, so lesson learned.