# JS click() event - Odd beheavior Chrome/IE8 if i click on the box vs the label

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, checkbox, onclick

I'm working on old website system and i'm having problems debugging this beheavior and i don't know why it happens (this is legacy code so i can't make any changes, just some patches)

**EDIT**: This system works on IE8 but now they are changing the browsers and it need to work on modern browsers or at least on chromium

I have a checkbox that is checked on the load of the page. if i click on it, it will fire the onclick() event and inside it has a click()[2] event again.

**Chrome:**

If i click on the checkbox (box) it doesnt let you uncheck it, because the click()[2] event it's fired and check it again

but if i click on de **label "TEST Check"** it let you change it to unchecked, because the click()[2] event is not fired, it skip it
Why only works on the label?

**Internet explorer 8:**

On IE, always skip the click()[2] so it works like i have pressed the label con Chrome

And yes, this code is horrible, but i just wonder why the label skip the click() event

Try it here: https://codepen.io/spuncko/pen/LYBavzx

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="CHK_NH_30" id="CHK_NH_30" onClick="changeHidden(this.checked, document.getElementById('HD_CHECK')); pressClick();" /> TEST Check
    <input type="hidden"          name="HD_CHECK"              id="HD_CHECK"                value="N"/>
</label>

</body>
<script>
    pressClick();
    
    function changeHidden(checked, hdobj){
        if (checked){
            hdobj.value = "Y";
        }else{
            hdobj.value = "N";
        }
    }
    function pressClick(){
        console.log("pressClick function");     
        
        if (document.getElementById("HD_CHECK").value == "N") {
            document.getElementById("CHK_NH_30").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("CHK_NH_30").click(); //click[2]
        }
    }
</script>
</html>
```

I expected that the **label** would have fired the click() event too and not skip it
So box and label would work the same (even if is not as IE8, but at least is consistent)

Comment: Please clarify.  You have legacy code written for IE8 that you want to run in modern browsers?

Comment: @Yogi Yes, it need to work now on modern browsers. I edited the post. thanks

Comment: What is that code supposed to be doing? You set it to "N" and it should undisable the checkbox and click the checkbox again to make it "Y" ????

Comment: @epascarello The code is old so i think, because IE8 skip the click() event, this worked so far but Chrome doesn't skip it unless you press on the label "TEST Check" where it skip it. I don't need to solve this problem i just want to know, why chrome skip it only on the label but not in the box (to see if i could have any other beheaviors)

Comment: The code should be using change event and not a click event

Comment: @epascarello without correcting the code, do you have any idea why on Chrome, works only clicking on the label instead on the box?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501497/why-the-onclick-element-will-trigger-twice-for-label-element

Comment: You can fix the problem without any JavaScript by simply adding a css rule: label input { pointer-events: none; }   This way only the label wrapper triggers a click event.