# React Why is label causing onClick event to run 2 times?

Tags: reactjs

Why the label with an input inside causes `onClick` to run 2 times?

```js
const { StrictMode } = React;
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;

function App() {
  return (
    <label className="label" onClick={()=> console.log("label onClick")}>
      <input className="radio" type="radio" />
    </label>
  );
}

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<StrictMode><App /></StrictMode>);
```

```css
.label {
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.radio {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it, please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Are you using React 18?

Comment: I was able to reproduce it in React 18, interesting.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label), "_When a user clicks or touches/taps a label, the browser passes the focus to its associated input (the resulting event is also raised for the input)_". I guess that's why.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why the onclick element will trigger twice for label element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501497/why-the-onclick-element-will-trigger-twice-for-label-element)

Comment: I got answers, now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In combination with the [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76930431/react-why-is-label-causing-onclick-event-to-run-2-times#comment135618376_76930431) by
@M0ns3R:

> According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label), "When a user clicks or touches/taps a label, the browser passes the focus to its associated input (the resulting event is also raised for the input)". I guess that's why.

And *event propagation* ([react.dev docs](https://react.dev/learn/responding-to-events#event-propagation)) is the cause for *double calls* of the `onClick`  event on the `label` element.

Here's what happens (*by **default***):

1. Clicking on `label` calls its `onClick`,
2. Then it triggers **`focus`** on the very first (top-to-bottom) `input` element;
3. The event bubbles up to its parent (*`label`*) and re-calls its `onClick` (*2nd time*).

One way to prevent the default bubbling phase is to pass an `onClick` to the very first `input` element and inside its callback call `e.stopPropagation`.

The code on CodeSandbox:

[image: Edit polished-morning-7dlfxs]

(To prove it you can copy one of the `input` *without an `onClick`* and paste it above the `input` *with* the `onClick`, and see it for yourself that clicking on `label` now *again* fires its `onClick` twice.)

A second way (*I left it commented out, so you can uncomment & test*) is to simply call `e.preventDefault()` inside the `label`'s `onClick` event handler function. Now you can *remove* the very first `input`'s `onClick` and see that the double calls have been fixed.