# If an element is wrapped by a label, does the label require the "for" attribute?

Tags: html, accessibility, section508

Say I have a set of radio `<input>`s. I'm not a caveman, so I know I need to associate `<label>` with those `<input>`s. I'm fond of wrapping the radio buttons within their corresponding labels, for [reasons enumerated here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/47920/27501).

So, for example:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Should I provide a "for" attribute?</legend>
    <label><input type="radio" name="define_the_for_attribute" id="define_the_for_attribute_yes" value="yes" />Yep, if you know what's good for you</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="define_the_for_attribute" id="define_the_for_attribute_no" value="no" />Nah, that would be redundant and repetitive</label>
</fieldset>
```

This wrapping associates the corresponding radio button with the label. Do I *also* need to define the label's `for` attribute?

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Should I provide a "for" attribute?</legend>
    <label for="define_the_for_attribute_yes"><input type="radio" name="define_the_for_attribute" id="define_the_for_attribute_yes" value="yes" />Yep, if you know what's good for you</label>
    <label for="define_the_for_attribute_no"><input type="radio" name="define_the_for_attribute" id="define_the_for_attribute_no" value="no" />Nah, that would be redundant and repetitive</label>
</fieldset>
```

[As pointed out](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/35297/27501) by [@Peter](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/27488/peter), "The for attribute of the label element must refer to a form control" (see http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/label.html), but this could be read to mean "if you specify the optional `for` attribute, it must refer to a valid form control".

Comment: How this is associated with accessibility?

Comment: Associating input elements with their labels is one of the foundational techniques for making web applications accessible.

Comment: @c-smile labels are very important for making forms accessible. They let the user of a screen reader know what a given field is for.

Comment: @c-smile: The `for` attribute is mainly a accessibility feature, relating a short description to a field. Also has functional uses, such as in checkbox: clicking its label also toggles its state.

Comment: @Nick I believe you are mixing usability and accessibility here. There are aria-labeledby, aria-description and the like attributes. The `for` and `label` wrapping in HTML is strictly UI/UX feature. They have some a11y value as they establish  association between input with some readable text.

Comment: @c-smile the `for` attribute is important for both UX and a11y cases. Not all browsers and screenreaders understand `aria-*` attributes. See: http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H44.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the HTML5 spec - "If the for attribute is not specified, but the label element has a labelable element descendant, then the first such descendant in tree order is the label element's labeled control."

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#category-label

So basically, no it is not required as long as it is wrapping any of these elements: button, input (if the type attribute is not in the hidden state), keygen, meter, output, progress, select, or textarea

Answer (score 3):

By the specifications, you don’t need the `for` attribute when the control element is wrapped inside a `label` element. This principle also applies to all modern browsers, though some very old versions of IE supported only the explicit association with `for` attributes.

People may still prefer to use the `for` attribute on logical grounds: a control is logically not part of a label, so it should be placed outside it. And then you need the `for` attribute in order to benefit from `label` markup at all.

The `for` attribute is necessarily when the control *cannot* be a descendant of a `label` element, e.g. when you have labels in one column of a `table` element, controls in another column.