# ADA compliance - Wrapping input in label vs adding label before input

Tags: html, accessibility, wcag

I am working on a website to implement ADA compliance. Which is better approach in terms of ADA compliance:

```
<label>Name:</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" />
```

**VS**

```
<label>
 Name:
 <input type="text" placeholder="Name" />
</label>
```

Similarly for other input types such as select, radio button, checkbox etc.

**Also we don't need labels in majority of forms as per design, so does it will make difference for ADA compliance if I add hidden labels for inputs?**

Similar thing is asked in below question but it doesn't answer in terms of ADA.

[Is it better to wrap the label tag around a form item or use the "for" attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11992026/is-it-better-to-wrap-the-label-tag-around-a-form-item-or-use-the-for-attribute)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebAIM.org gives advice on ADA and forms at the link below.

[Creating Accessible Forms](http://webaim.org/techniques/forms/controls#javascript)

Below is the method they  recommended.

```
<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input id="name" type="text" name="textfield">
```

Whether hidden labels have any advantage or not in ADA is still a mystery.