# How do i make an input field bigger with CSS?

Tags: html, css

How do I make an input field bigger with CSS? I have a separate CSS file and want to make this bigger

```css
#txtbox {
  font-size: 18pt;
  height: 42px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Mehr lesen Button -->
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn" type="button">Mehr lesen</button>

<span id="more" style="display: none;">
  <p>Sonstiges: &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text"  name="sonstiges"  /></p>
</span>
```

Comment: you need to add the id to your input otherwise you are not styling it

Comment: Also p is not a valid child of a span. Use a DIV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code. You need to give id to input box. Hope it will help you. If any changes please let me know.

```css
#txtbox {
  font-size: 18pt;
  height: 42px;
  width : 300px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Mehr lesen Button -->
<button id="myBtn" type="button">Mehr lesen</button>
    
<div id="more">
  <label>Sonstiges: </label>
    <input type="text"  name="sonstiges" id="txtbox" />
</div>
```

Comment: Also why not `<label>Sonstiges: 
    <input type="text"  name="sonstiges" id="txtbox" /></label>`

Comment: Tried it but it still dosen't work for whatever reason.  The size of the input field is always the same its not changing

Comment: @mplungjan Please follow this link : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

Comment: w3schools is a poor resource

Comment: @Cepturion Do want 100% width of input box?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11992026/is-it-better-to-wrap-the-label-tag-around-a-form-item-or-use-the-for-attribute

Comment: So either wrap or use `<label for="txtbox">Sonstiges: </label>
    <input type="text"  name="sonstiges" id="txtbox" />`

Comment: @RevtiShah I want to change the height of it.

Comment: @Cepturion Can you just give me a clear picture of your output. So I can guide you in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#txtbox {
  font-size: 18pt;
  height: 42px;
  width: 300px;
}
 .text{
  font-size: 18px;
 }
```

```html
<!-- Mehr lesen Button -->
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn" type="button"><text>Mehr lesen</text></button>

<span id="more" style="display: none;">
  <p>Sonstiges: &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" class="text" name="sonstiges"  /></p>
</span>
```